# Update displayed tool tips for elements of QXXXView (QTableView, QTreeView,...) in a model/view scenario

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to update the *active* tool tip of a view widget of an [model/view scenario](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). The tool tip is determined by calling `data` of the model with the `Qt::ToolTipRole` role.

However, I don't find any solution to update a displayed/*active* tool tip due to a change of data. Scenarios are, for instance, some time-based tool tips or image tool tips with a preview while the image is loading.

I went through some time researching for a solution and I want to share a possible answer to the above question.

**EDIT:**
Emitting `dataChanged` with the `Qt::ToolTipRole` alone doesn't seem to update an active tool tip, here's my minimal example for a `QTableViewModel` model (tested with Qt5):

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyModel(QObject *parent = 0) : QAbstractTableModel(parent), i(0) {
        QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
        timer->setInterval(500);
        connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyModel::onNewTime);
        timer->start();
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const { return 1; }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const { return 1; }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &, int role) const {
        switch(role){
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
            return "Hund";
        case Qt::ToolTipRole:
            return i;
        default:
            return QVariant();
        }
    }
private slots:
    void onNewTime() {
        i+=1;
        QModelIndex model = index(0,0);
        emit dataChanged(model, model, QVector<int>()<<Qt::ToolTipRole);
    }
private:
    int i;
};
```

Comment: Does your model correctly emit a `dataChanged()` signal with `Qt::ToolTipRole` in the `roles` argument (or an empty `roles`)?  If not, fix that first!

Comment: Good point, I've tested your suggestion but it doesn't seem to update/replace an active tool tip, if I've tried correctly (see updated question). Btw, the same seems to hold for any `QWidget`: calling `setToolTip(...)` doesn't seem to update an active tool tip (it would need `hideText`/`showText`)

Comment: TBH, I suspected that it was unlikely to change once showing, but I did want to be sure that you'd at least tried that.  Thanks for updating the question to show what you did.

Answer (score 2):

The first idea to subclass, for instance, `QTableView` fails, since neither `eventFilter(...)` `event(...)` nor `helpEvent(...)` are called with a `QEvent::ToolTip`-event.

I ended up re-implementing `viewportEvent(...)` to catch a `QEvent::ToolTip` event. Also I had to make sure the tool-tip popup would not be updated once the mouse had been moved.

This is my solution. It will basically close and re-open the tool tip on a data change. To update a tool tip while it is running, just call or connect to the slot `showOrUpdateToolTip`. First the subclassing of `QTableView`:

```
class TableViewToolTipModifier : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TableViewToolTipModifier(QWidget *parent=0);
public slots:
    void showOrUpdateToolTip();
protected:
    bool viewportEvent(QEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *);
private:
    QPoint _lastPosition;
    bool _isActive = false;
};
```

The implementation:

```
TableViewToolTipModifier::TableViewToolTipModifier(QWidget* parent)
    : QTableView(parent)
{
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
}

void TableViewToolTipModifier::showOrUpdateToolTip()
{
    if (QTableView::underMouse() && _isActive)
    {
        const QModelIndex index = QTableView::indexAt(
                                       this->mapFromGlobal(_lastPosition));
        if (index.isValid())
        {
            const QString toolTip = index.data(Qt::ToolTipRole).toString();
            QToolTip::showText(_lastPosition, toolTip, this, QRect());
        }
    }
}

void TableViewToolTipModifier::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    _isActive = false;
     QToolTip::hideText();

     QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

bool TableViewToolTipModifier::viewportEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
    {
        _lastPosition = static_cast<QHelpEvent*>(event)->globalPos();
        _isActive = true;
        showOrUpdateToolTip();
        return true;
    }
    return QTableView::viewportEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use model/view approach the only thing you need to do is writing an appropriate code in your model's data() function, i.e. `QAbstactItemModel::data()`. The code should look like:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &item, int role) const
{
  if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  {
    return "This is view item text";
  }
  else if (role == Qt::ToolTipRole)
  {
    // Here you should decide what to return.
    if (someCondition)
      return "This is the actual tool tip";
    else
      return "Something else";
  }
  return QAbstractItemModel::data(item, role);
}
```

Thus, your model has to return the actual tool tip text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issues is, when the tool tip data is being displayed and meanwhile it's being changed - without the user moving the mouse, then the tool tip doesn't get updated.

Comment: Yes. That's because tool tip is a static information. It should be re-opened again to show new state.

Comment: You also need to emit `dataChanged()`, but it might still be that the view doesn't respond to that.